# XNA Font Metrics

Tags: c#, fonts, xna

FontFamily has methods to get font metrics but I can't get System.Drawing with my XNA Project. 
The FontFamily class has perfect methods for what I need which is aligning text. Here is a great article if you can use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx

I am needing to figure out the bounding box of a string without the line-spacing/line-height. Spritefont has a method called MeasureString but it includes line-spacing.

How can I get font metrics in a XNA project?

Although I can get the metrics from any method I am using the Nuclex processor so it uses FreeType. Looks like it is possible to use in .NET: http://icarus.sourceforge.net/Content/Tutorials/Developer/dev_freetype.html

Comment: How can you have a bounding box if you ignore line height? I think I misunderstand you!

Comment: @Joe Need just pixel space it takes up. See "Height" in this diagram: http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/metrics.png